# Multiple quotation marks in-vba formula

Tags: excel, vba

My first coding is working properly and return correct answer.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("I2:I" & LastROwColumnList).Formula = "=IF(MID(F2,8,3)=""T_2"",""Team_A"",""NA2"")"
```

but it doesnt work when trying to put more conditions in formula

```
ActiveSheet.Range("I2:I" & LastROwColumnList).Formula = "=IF(MID(F2,8,3)=""T_2"",""Team_A"",IF(MID(F2,8,3)=""P_9"",""Team_B"",""NA"")"
```

How should I modify it?

Answer (score 1):

Enter the formula manually in the sheet, then go to the debug window and type

```
print activecell.formula
```

You can then double the inner quotes, or replace them by single quotes, and your're done.
You can even automate that step (I wrote [that](http://idevlop.blogspot.com/2009/09/generer-du-vba-avec-excel-vba.html) in 2009):

```
 Sub RngToVba(src As Range)  
 'writes the VBA code to re-create the formulae in given range  
 'by Patrick Honorez - www.idevlop.com  
 'usage: from debug window, type RngToVba [L14:R14]  
 ' or RngToVba range("L14:R14")  
  Dim c As Range  
  For Each c In src  
  Debug.Print "range(""" & c.Address & """).formula = """ & _  
        Replace(c.Formula, """", """""") & """"""  
  Next c  
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis for the outer IF function since you added an inner IF function.

This should do it:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("I2:I" & LastROwColumnList).Formula = "=IF(MID(F2,8,3)=""T_2"",""Team_A"",IF(MID(F2,8,3)=""P_9"",""Team_B"",""NA""))"
```